# How to set default value of \ChoiceMenu as combo using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, default

I can't assign default values for `\ChoiceMenu`s in combomode. Everything I find (Google), indicates that it should work this way (like it works with `\TextField`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

    \ChoiceMenu[combo,name=testMenu,default=Test]{bla1:}{Test1,Test2}\\
    \\
    \TextField[name=testField,default=Test]{bla2:}
    
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't matter if I try it with `value` or `default` or both.

I use `hyperref` Version 7.00u and MikTex 22.12

Crosspost(https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=24856)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sad but hyperref's form field implementation has a number of bugs. In this case it applies `\pdfstringdef` twice to the value. This means that the /Opt array contains this values (this is correct):

```
/Opt[(\376\377\000T\000e\000s\000t\0001)
     (\376\377\000T\000e\000s\000t\0002)]
```

But the default values look like this:

```
 /DV(\376\377\376\377\000\000T\000\000e\000\000s\000\000t\000\0001)
 /V(\376\377\376\377\000\000T\000\000e\000\000s\000\000t\000\0001)
```

You can try this patch:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\HyField@PDFChoices
  {\xdef\Fld@choices{\Fld@choices/DV(\Hy@gtemp)}}%
  {\xdef\Fld@choices{\Fld@choices/DV(\Fld@default)}}
  {}{\fail}
  
\patchcmd\HyField@PDFChoices
  {\xdef\Fld@choices{\Fld@choices/V(\Hy@gtemp)}}%
  {\xdef\Fld@choices{\Fld@choices/V(\Fld@value)}}
  {}{\fail}
  
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\ChoiceMenu[width=4cm,combo,name=testMenu,value=Test1]{bla1:}{Test1,Test2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

But be aware that there are probably more bugs in the implementation.

An alternative is to use eforms or the form fields from the PDF management:

```
\DocumentMetadata{} %load pdf management
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\pdffieldchoice\pdffield_choice:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\pdffieldchoice{width=4cm,name=test,setfieldflags={Combo},default=test1, values={test1,test2,test3}}

\end{document}
```