# How to add Text Widget Annotations to a pdf form?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf, forms

I am trying to create a fillable pdf form using Latex.

**Backstory:**
I have a pdf form that can be both filled  in by a person or by using a python script. That pdf was created using inkscape, libreoffice writer, and pdftk. The basic layout of the form was created in inkscape. The svg was exported as a pdf. The exported pdf was opened in libreoffice writer, where the formfields were added. One of my forms had 2 pages, so each page would be created as separate pdfs then joined together using pdftk. The result is a pdf form that can be filled either by a human or by a script. I then created a python script that uses pdfrw to fill in a number of the form fields.

The problem is that making changes to the form is long and overly complex process. I am trying to create the form using latex.

I have created a form in latex that can be filled by a human, but the python script can't find anything to fill in.

I think the problem is that I am missing **text widget annotations** or **widget annotations** from the pdf that is generated from the latex file.

The following is one of thee **text widget annotations** that is in the original pdf (form) but not in the pdf (form) generated from the latex file:

```
34 0 obj
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/F 4
/Rect[54.027 494.192 557.377 557.261]
/FT/Tx
/P 19 0 R
/T(partsRequired)
/Ff 4096
/V <FEFF>
/DV <FEFF>
/DR<</Font 6 0 R>>
/DA(0.1372549019 0.1490196078 0.1607843137 rg /He 10.006 Tf)
/AP<<
/N 79 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
```

I have used `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\pdfminorversion=6` in my latex document, but the resultant pdf does not have any **text widget annotations**.

What am I doing wrong?

form.tex:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pdfminorversion=6
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=8mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
    #1 \raisebox{-3.0pt}{#2}%
}
\newlength\templength
\newcommand{\DefaultTextField}[2][]{%
    \settowidth\templength{#2 }%
    \mbox{\TextField[align=1,bordercolor=0.78 0.78 0.75,backgroundcolor={},#1,height=4ex,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\templength]{#2}}%
}
\newlength\templengthtwo
\newcommand{\DefaultTextFieldMultiline}[2][]{%
    \settowidth\templengthtwo{#2 }%
    \mbox{\TextField[align=1,bordercolor=0.78 0.78 0.75,backgroundcolor={},#1,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\templengthtwo]{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\LayoutCheckField[2]{%
    \raisebox{-1.0pt}{#2}\hspace*{2mm}#1%
}
\newcommand{\DefaultCheckBox}[2][]{%
    \mbox{\CheckBox[bordercolor=0 0 0,backgroundcolor={},borderwidth=0.4mm,height=5mm,width=5mm,#1]{#2}}%
}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
            \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
            \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
            \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
        }%
        \item[]}{\end{list}}


\begin{document}
    
    %\def\DefaultHeightofText[12pt]
    \def\DefaultHeightofText{14pt}%
    
    \begin{Form}        
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{-2.5ex}
            \underline{\large\textbf{Customer Receipt}}
        \end{center}
        
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{-0.5ex}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
                \DefaultCheckBox[name=collectCheckBox]{Collection } &
                \DefaultCheckBox[name=dropoffCheckBox]{Dropoff } &
                \DefaultCheckBox[name=returnCheckBox]{Return }
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        
        \begin{flushleft}
            \section{Device Details}
            \vspace{-0.5ex}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
            \noindent
            \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
                \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=makeAndModel,width=0.25\textwidth]{Make \& Model }} \vspace{.7ex} \\
                
                \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=serialNumber,width=0.25\textwidth]{Serial Number }}
            \end{tabular}
            
        \end{flushleft}
        
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry but how should we know what you are doing wrong if you don't show any code?

Comment: @David Fear: It is hard to help you without a minimal reproducible example... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I have add the code of form.tex file.

Comment: @mrCarnivore -  I have add the code of form.tex file.

Comment: your example is way too long.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - i have changed the example to a much shorter one.

Comment: now build the same in libreoffice and put it somewhere for download (but naturally it would be better if there were only one field in both). Check if your script is really working with the one and failing with the other!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I have uploaded files to: https://testing.dfear.co.uk/tex/

Screenshot_20230425_221223.png - Libreoffice writer - export to pdf - options selected.
customer-receipt-form.test.fom_controls.pdf - pdf exported from libreoffice writer.
customer-receipt-form.test.pdf - pdf exported from inkscape.
customer-receipt-form.test.svg - The form layout in svg. designed in inkscape.
customer-receipt-form.test.tex - basically the same form in tex.

Comment: well the widget is there. Perhaps your script gets confused by the different field names. You could try `\makeatletter\def\PDFForm@@Name#1{}
\makeatother`. Or try to build the field with l3pdffield-testphase, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669186/2388

Comment: in both (you can uncompress the latex one with `\ExplSyntaxOn\sys_ensure_backend:\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff` to check).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - in which pdf file does the widget occur?